Why is it "rude or abusive" to ask if Kamala Harris engaged in prosecutorial misconduct?
Could DaleM please help us understand what was "rude or abusive" about a question asking whether Kamala Harris had concealed evidence of a defendant's innocence?
The question had been closed with a recommendation to be moved to Politics, but there was at least one vote to reopen pending when DaleM deleted the question altogether, marking it as "rude or abusive."

Why was that process not allowed to play out?

Regarding the confusion of the "spam or rude or abusive" text: It appears from the question history that explanation was automatically added by the system because at least one user had flagged it with one of those reasons and a moderator had marked that flag "Helpful."

It isn't rude or abusive
It's just not a question about law. People being interviewed by the media are not required to answer questions, or, for that matter, to answer truthfully if they do.
It might be on topic in politics.
That said, I was wrong to delete it and it’s now been undeleted.

I largely agree with that. But if that's the explanation, why did you delete it as "rude or abusive," rather than letting the community decide whether to reopen, or letting OP rewrite it so it was on topic?

From the answer by @feetwet, it sounds like you may didn't designate it as "rude or abusive" yourself. But I think the underlying question remains unanswered: Why did you delete the question instead of allowing the community decide whether to revise or reopen it?

The system marks deleted questions with extremely low score such.
We can't do anything there, even a mod deleting differently doesn't change it. The question had a score of -7 when Roomba got to it, and so it went to become obscurred automatically.
